# Where are the Gnome Fallback Configuration User Files?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gnome-fallback

I am trying to find the Gnome Panel layout File for the user. Under the User's Folder I'm not finding it under .gnome2 or .gconf or anything. I found the Default XML file under /usr/share/gnome-panel/panel-default-layout.layout. Any Ideas? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnome3 uses DConf instead of GConf. The Gnome Panel settings are at `org.gnome.gnome-panel`.

As DConf saves its data in binary form to improve performance you can't edit the settings  by hand but need to use  the command line tools `gsettings` (package libglib2.0-bin) or `dconf` (package dconf-tools) or the GUI `dconf-editor` (package dconf-tools) to view or edit them.